# Get Oracle Metadata with Primary Key

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata

Can someone help me with Oracle access to these data elements and Primary key definition?

All I want is distinct definition of tables supplied to this query

```
SELECT TotalColumn.*
  FROM 
    (SELECT FirstLevel.*
    --,NULL AS CONSTRAINT_TYPE
    ,'ORACLE' AS DB_Source_Name
    FROM (SELECT  
            A.COLUMN_NAME , 
            A.DATA_TYPE  , 
            A.DATA_LENGTH , 
            A.NULLABLE ,
            A.COLUMN_ID 
            A.DATA_PRECISION ,
            A.DATA_SCALE 
        --(I want to add contraint CONSTRAINT_NAME)
      FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS A
    where A.OWNER ='SCHEMA_NAME'AND A.TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
    ) FirstLevel 
) TotalColumn
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

[stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmljj.png).imgur.com/vEfpy.png

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` and `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` to get the constraint information.

Following is the query which will give you the Primary key name for the column. You can also play around with these tables to get any kind of result.

```
SELECT
    A.COLUMN_NAME,
    A.DATA_TYPE,
    A.DATA_LENGTH,
    A.NULLABLE,
    A.COLUMN_ID,
    A.DATA_PRECISION,
    A.DATA_SCALE,
    CASE
        WHEN AC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P' THEN ACC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    END PRIMARY_KEY_CONS_NAME,
        --(I want to add contraint CONSTRAINT_NAME)
    'ORACLE' AS DB_SOURCE_NAME
FROM
    ALL_TAB_COLUMNS A
    LEFT JOIN ALL_CONS_COLUMNS ACC ON A.COLUMN_NAME = ACC.COLUMN_NAME
                                      AND A.TABLE_NAME = ACC.TABLE_NAME
                                      AND A.OWNER = ACC.OWNER
    LEFT JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS AC ON AC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ACC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                    AND AC.OWNER = ACC.OWNER
WHERE
    A.OWNER = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
    AND A.TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME'
ORDER BY
    A.COLUMN_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only table (actually, it's a view) involved is ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.  It is documented in the *[Database Reference Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-F218205C-7D76-4A83-8691-BFD2AD372B63.htm#REFRN20277)*.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a table I can join to to get the Primary Key(Constraint Name and Constraint Type). These are the two columnist that I am not getting correctly

Comment: There is no primary key on that view.  What is it you are not getting correctly? What is it you are _really_ trying to achieve?  Have you tried the solution offered by @Tejash?